# Stopwatch program( implementing exception )

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, stopwatch

i got this task of creating a stopwatch, heres the task.

[image: Stopwatch Task]

now the problem is that i cant implement the invalid operation exception and also i used goto statement in my code and i caught myself using that in my last program as well and i dont know if its a good thing to use it as often as i do. is that a good practice?
I'm a beginner and please be as critical as you can with my code. point out every possiblity you can see to improve my code. I dont care if you completely change the logic, It will help me that much to learn. 
Thank you so much for your time. Here's the code. I cant use the framework's stopwatch class by the way.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var starting = new Stopwatch();
        var x = 0; // mechanics to stop user from using start method twice if x==2 it should throw exception, which i havent implemented yet.
        StartWatch:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Y to start the stopwatch and press N to stop");
            var start = Console.ReadLine();
            if (start != null && start.ToUpper()=="Y")
            {
                starting.StartMethod();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch Started");
                x += 1;
            goto StartWatch;
            }
            else if (start != null && start.ToUpper() == "N")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(starting.Stop());
                x = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("press R to reset and enter to exit");
                if (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()=="R")
                    goto StartWatch;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, Enter either \"Y\" to start or \"N\" to Stop the Stopwatch");
                goto StartWatch;
            }

    }
}
```

This is the Stopwatch class:

```
public class Stopwatch
{
    public DateTime Startwatch { get; private set; }

    public void StartMethod()
    {
        this.Startwatch = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public TimeSpan Stop()
    {
        var totalTime = DateTime.Now - Startwatch;
        return totalTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a loop in your main program. However, if you want critiques of your working code you should head over to [codereview.se] but please take a look at their help pages and other questions on the site before posting.

Comment: thanks for your insight and yes i did implement the code in a while loop with true and break but isnt it processer demanding to use while loop than a goto statement?

Comment: don't use a `goto`

Comment: Code Review is the proper place for this question.